# Calculated Class property from another Class Property (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this

I have a class with a constructor and as below:

```
class Bookshelf {  
 constructor(author, publisher) {
  this.books = [],
  this.numBooks = this.books.length
  this.author = author,
  this.publsiher = publisher
 }
}
```

I am not getting back the value of the book array which is what I truly want to do. I know `this` is causing the value not to be grabbed but I really want to understand why?

Comment: What are those commas there for? Use semicolons instead. Also, it's not clear what you're looking for, `books` is initialized to an empty array...?

Comment: Can you show some more code that demonstrates the problem? I'm not sure what your goal is.

Comment: `new Bookshelf().books` should return the empty array you've assigned to `this.books` - but I agree with the previous comments, your "problem" is hard to perceive

Comment: @4castle I am going to create books and want to add them to the `Bookshelf` and then print the `Bookshelf` instance to see what it contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret this question, based on the title, to be asking why `numBooks` doesn't update after you add an entry to `books` within a `Bookshelf` you create.

When you run the statement `this.numBooks = this.books.length`, it does set a property called `numBooks` to the calculated value `this.books.length`, which is `0`. Later, you might add a value to `books`, but that doesn't affect `numBooks`.

The problem isn't about *calculating one "class property" from another* so much as *understanding that `numBooks` stores a number, and that number doesn't update automatically*. Your constructor runs once, and that's it.

Compare with this:

```
class Bookshelf {  
 constructor(author, publisher) {
  this.books = [];
  this.author = author;
  this.publisher = publisher;
 }

 getNumBooks() {
  return this.books.length;
 }
}

let myBookshelf = new Bookshelf("Isaac Asimov", "Bantam Press");
myBookshelf.books.push("I, Robot");
console.log(myBookshelf.getNumBooks());   // prints 1
```

Because your call to `getNumBooks()` runs code, it can calculate the dynamic value `this.books.length`, which is why it gives you an up-to-date value where the property `numBooks` doesn't update automatically. If you'd rather keep `numBooks` as a property, you also have the option of making the `books` property private, and instead exposing an `addBook` function that adds a book and resets `numBooks` accordingly.

As Patrick reminds me in the comments, since you specified ES6, you can use [getter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to write a function that acts like a property. This works because it runs code when you refer to `numBooks`, even though the syntax hides that detail away.

```
class Bookshelf {  
 constructor(author, publisher) {
  this.books = [];
  this.author = author;
  this.publisher = publisher;
 }

 get numBooks() {
  return this.books.length;
 }
}

let myBookshelf = new Bookshelf("Isaac Asimov", "Bantam Press");
myBookshelf.books.push("I, Robot");
console.log(myBookshelf.numBooks());   // prints 1
```

Comment: or `get numBooks()`

Comment: This is very close to what I am trying to do but if I wanted to add the number of books to the instance `myBookshelf` I would do so with `myBookshelf.numOfBooks = myBookshelf.getNumBooks()`

But how would this be done dynamically?

Comment: @Justlearning Prior to ES6, your options would be to make `getNumBooks()` a function as I have, or to write a function that adds to the `books` array (e.g. `addBook`) that keeps your `numBooks` property updated. Since ES6, though, Patrick rightly points out that you can [write a "getter" using ES6 "get syntax"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) that actually runs a function but _looks_ like a normal property. You wouldn't ever explicitly set `this.numBooks` to a number, but `myBookshelf.numBooks` or `this.numBooks` would act like you want.